# Successful high voltage (400 V DC) measurement with isolation

Tags: high-voltage, voltage-measurement, isolation, ground-loop

I want to make a precharge system for an electric car for which I require voltage measurement.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Stepping the voltage down through voltage divider (0-5 V) range (high side).
2. Feeding this analogue value to an [i2c ADC](https://www.ti.com/sitesearch/en-us/docs/universalsearch.tsp?langPref=en-US&searchTerm=ads1115&nr=486#q=ads1115&numberOfResults=25) (high side).
3. Use an [i2c isolator](https://www.ti.com/product/ISO1540-Q1) that will feed the isolated signal to the low voltage side microcontroller which will in turn turn on contactors.

The issue is if I don't give the high side ground to the ADC, I won't be able to  measure voltage correctly (correct me if I am wrong). I have to power the ADC from the high voltage side.

I don't have a DC/DC converter on hand right now and don't plan to buy anytime soon (costly and time constraint).

How can I power the measurement system through the high side?

Comment: You need 5 V, 5 mA on the HV side, a small DC/DC converter is perfect there. If you don't want to use one, take a 80 kohm 3 W resistor to burn the voltage down and a 5.1 V Z-diode to stabilize the voltage.

Comment: You have a high DC voltage (400V) and an isolated DC voltage (low voltage side). You want to turn this into a lower DC voltage on the high-voltage side. That means you want to turn one DC voltage into another DC voltage. A circuit that does this is a DC/DC converter by definition - DC in, DC out. There's no way around it. An off-line flyback converter IC (designed for AC/DC operation) can also be used for DC/DC conversion. They're incredibly cheap. There are also isolated 1W DC/DC bricks that cost a dollar or two.